# how to check if insert or update will affect result of a select query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE station 
  (title CHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY, 
   city CHAR(20),
   latitude REAL, 
   longitude REAL);
```

And I have some queries, for example **Q1**:

```
SELECT * FROM station WHERE latitude > 50 AND longitude > 90;
```

**Q2**:

```
SELECT * FROM station WHERE latitude > 50 OR longitude > 90;
```

How can I determine that next insert query:

```
INSERT INTO station VALUES ("Station 1", "London", 60, 10)
```

will change result of **Q2** but not **Q1**?

Assuming that select queries can be infinitely complex, sometimes it can be hard to answer such question, that's why false positives are suitable.

---

In other words, how do I write such function (Python)?

```
def can_affect(insert_query: str, select_query: str) -> bool:
    """
    Tells if particular insert query can affect results of select query. 

    Returns False if there is no chance that insert will affect select query.
    Otherwise, returns True.
    """
```

Comment: Will the queries you're testing always deal with only the single table? Or will there be cases where joins to other tables are part of the query?

Comment: @MikeTheReader, yes, query can contain joins to other tables. For example, function must return **False** when giving **"SELECT a JOIN b JOIN c"** and **"INSERT INTO d"**.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: use a Postgres transaction.

1. Execute "BEGIN TRANSACTION READ WRITE;".
2. Perform the selection. Record the number of rows returned.
3. Perform the insertion.
4. Perform the selection again. Record the number of rows returned.
5. Execute "ROLLBACK;". This will undo any changes you made to the table.
6. If the number of rows differed between the selects, return true. Else, false.

Comment: Keep in mind that with Method A there is a chance between step 1 and step 2 that another process could add a record that might change the count. (It's a very small window, but it's not entirely impossible.)

Comment: The solution you've provided can be used under some circumstances, but in most cases it will not be effective. I would like to answer this question just by analyzing both queries + some information about database schema.

Comment: In what cases would it not be effective? I'd be interested in seeing a case in which it wouldn't be.

Comment: I'd also not advise trying to parse queries or schemas yourself. In general, it's better to **let the tool do the work**, and **manipulate the functionality provided.** Don't pretend to be Postgres--it's too much work.

Comment: @PaulHoisington, If I will have 1000 different queries, I will need to perform 2000 select queries on each insert. I don't think that's effective.

I really would not like to write my own query parser, that's why I'm looking for some tool or APIs which provide such functionality.